# error while configuring Raspberry pi B+ wifi on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I am trying to configure raspberry pi WiFi on Raspbian. I get an error when typing this command.

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.4.2
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "iPhone"
wpa-psk "iphone4ss"
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Install the proper drivers for your adapter.

Comment: The configuration you have posted has many errors and will not work. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 for detail of how to set it up.

Comment: @SamiKobbi glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (after running update, upgrade, etc):

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-ssid "iPhone"
wpa-psk "iphone4ss"
```